# Math.round does not round off numbers

Tags: java, math, rounding

Good Evening,

My code won't round off, and I don't know why! Please help!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Arithmetic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int tipPercentage;  // tip percentage
        int taxPercentage;  // tax percentage
        int totalTip;       // total tip
        int totalTax;       // total tax
        double mealCost;    // original meal price
        double totalCost = 0.0; // total meal price

        // Write your calculation code here.
            mealCost = scan.nextDouble();
            tipPercentage = scan.nextInt ();
            taxPercentage = scan.nextInt();

            totalCost += mealCost;
            totalCost += mealCost*tipPercentage/100;
            totalCost += mealCost*taxPercentage/100;


        // cast the result of the rounding operation to an int and save it as totalCost 
            mealCost=(int)Math.round(totalCost);


        // Print your result
        System.out.println (" The total meal cost is " + totalCost + " dollars. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague, could you please edit it with a bit more detail on what the problem is

Comment: You have a typo, but the whole approach is fallacious. See my answer in the duplicate for why. If you want decimal places you must use a decimal radix, e.g. via `BigDecimal` or `DecimalFormat`, and in any case you should use `BigDecimal` for money, not floating-point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

mealCost is the variable that you are trying to round, whereas totalCost is the variable that you print out and display to the user.

`System.out.println (" The total meal cost is " + totalCost + " dollars. ");`

Also, when displaying cost it might be a good idea to round to the nearest hundredth. You can do this by saying something like

`mealCost=Math.round(totalCost*100)/100.0`

Finally, you should prompt the user, so they know what they are inputting in the console.

Comment: Thank you so much! that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Of course, in the examples above, you probably want to change mealCost to totalCost... I was just unsure of which one you wanted to print out.

Comment: you should use BigDecimal for money, not floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `totalCost` to your printed string, when you are assigning a rounded value to `mealCost`. In other words,

```
mealCost=(int)Math.round(totalCost);
```

should become

```
totalCost=(int)Math.round(totalCost);
```

Additionally, you may want to add prompts before taking in input as well as perhaps reconsidering your rounding, unless you really want it to the nearest dollar.

Comment: So this actually worked as it shows my total changing from 15.36, to 15.0... Is there a way to remove the .0 portion from the final result?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the .0 , then just cast mealCost as an int in your print statement.